# Javascript: Varying width multi dimension array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, variable-length

I want to create a 2D array, with varying width. I have initialized the outer array as I know the number of rows.

```
var listofcities = new Array(lengthofcites); //i get this lengthofcitles from another routine
```

Now, I will get the list of facilities in the cities from another routine as list. E.g. `listoffacilities = ["water","air"]` for a city. For another city I will get this list as `listoffacilities = ["water","air","electricity"]`.

I should be able to store this in my outer array in such a way that

```
listofcities[0] = ["water","air"]
listofcities[1] = ["water","air","electricity"]
```

I'm not able to use the push function like `listofcities[0].push(listoffacilities)` in the inner loop.

All the examples I could see from web have same sized rows/columns.

Comment: *"I'm not able to use the push function..."* Why not?

Comment: What is `listofcities`? It sounds like you're not initialising it, hence why `.push` wouldn't work

Comment: @George - The op shows it in the question: `var listofcities = new Array(lengthofcities);`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My bad, I missed that, thank you; makes sense why `listofcities[0].push` isn't working then.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays; it has arrays of arrays. So multi-dimensional arrays are inherently *jagged* (the term for when not all subordinate arrays are of the same length).

You do it literally as you've shown:

```js
var listofcities = []; // No need to pre-allocate length
listofcities[0] = ["water","air"];
listofcities[1] = ["water","air","electricity"];
console.log(listofcities);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

This:

```
var listofcities = [];
```

creates an empty outer array, and then these:

```
listofcities[0] = ["water","air"];
listofcities[1] = ["water","air","electricity"];
```

create subordinate arrays (e.g., `["water","air"]`) and store them in that outer array. `[...]` is an *array initializer* (often called an "array literal") that creates an array with the items between the brackets.

Here's an example using `push`; note that you call `push` on the array (`listofcities.push(...)`), not an an *entry* in that array (`listofcities[0].push(...)`). But once you've put a subordinate array in as an entry, you *can* `push` to that subordinate array (`listofcities[0].push(...)`).

```js
var listofcities = []; // No need to pre-allocate length
listofcities.push(["water","air"]);
listofcities.push(["water","air","electricity"]);
console.log(listofcities);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be pushing onto a specific element of `listofcities`, just push onto the array itself:

```js
var listofcities = []; // don't specify the length here
listoffacilities = ["water", "air"];
listofcities.push(listoffacilities);
listoffacilities = ["water","air","electricity"];
listofcities.push(listoffacilities);
console.log(listofcities);
```